# Z layout adding weird spacing on right side Outlook 2010 & 13

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I'm having a weird issue in Outlook with a Z layout for an email. Basically it's adding extra padding on top of the copy but ONLY on the right side of the layout. I've tried swapping between margin and padding and changing it to different elements (Tried it on the H6 tag and on the TH tag above that as well as on the table above that). Everything just seems to move the extra spacing around and it never actually goes away.

Here's how it looks in Outlook 2010 and 2013: https://www.evernote.com/l/AHEyfSHAvAJAb6LFDbEDYrECrb5NxxzEC_8

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ajrdesign/pen/PzEdvG) with the full HTML.

Below is the snippet containing the Z layout only:

```
<!-- ARTICLE 1
                LAYOUT = COPY > IMAGE
                TO DUPLICATE SELECT FROM ROW BELOW TO END ARTICLE 1 -->
                  <table class="row row-article" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="small-12 large-5 columns first" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 40px; text-align: left; width: 225.66667px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <h6 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                                <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/extremeconference/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                <!-- ^^^ ADD ARTICLE 1 LINK ABOVE -->
                                  <img class="article-arrow" width="25" height="20" src="http://www.bluebeam.com/us/email/variety/html/images/arrow-right-blue.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">

                                <!-- REPLACE CONTENT BELOW FOR ARTICLE 1 --> 
                                Last Chance to Register!
                              </a></h6>
                                  <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">There’s only one month left to get 50% off registration for the Bluebeam eXtreme Conference. Don't miss this opportunity to connect with customers. <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/extremeconference/" target="_blank"
                                      style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">Register today >></a></p>
                                  <!-- END OF CONTENT FOR ARTICLE 1 -->
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-7 columns last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 322.33333px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/extremeconference/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img src="https://downloads.bluebeam.com/images/2016/VARiety/16-07/article-1-excon-V3.jpg" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">
                                  </a>
                                  <!-- ^^^ ADD IMAGE 1 URL  -->
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- END ARTICLE 1 -->

                  <!-- ARTICLE 2
                LAYOUT = IMAGE > COPY
                TO DUPLICATE SELECT FROM ROW BELOW TO END ARTICLE 2 -->
                  <table class="row row-article" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="small-12 large-7 columns first" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 8px; text-align: left; width: 322.33333px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/2016/07/sellmoretoexistingcustomers/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img src="https://downloads.bluebeam.com/images/2016/VARiety/16-07/article-2-steve.jpg" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">
                                  </a>
                                  <!-- ^^^ ADD IMAGE 2 URL  -->
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-5 columns last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 16px; padding-top: 50px; text-align: left; width: 225.66667px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <h6 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                                <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/2016/07/sellmoretoexistingcustomers/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                <!-- ^^^ ADD ARTICLE 2 LINK ABOVE -->
                                  <img class="article-arrow" width="25" height="20" src="http://www.bluebeam.com/us/email/variety/html/images/arrow-left-blue.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">

                                <!-- REPLACE CONTENT BELOW FOR ARTICLE 2 --> 
                                Steve's Sales Tips
                              </a></h6>
                                  <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">Your next opportunity could be closer than you think. Learn how to engage your existing customers with <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/2016/07/sellmoretoexistingcustomers/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">these strategies >></a></p>
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- END ARTICLE 2 -->

                  <!-- ARTICLE 3
                LAYOUT = COPY > IMAGE
                TO DUPLICATE SELECT FROM ROW BELOW TO END ARTICLE 3 -->
                  <table class="row row-article" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="small-12 large-5 columns first" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 45px; text-align: left; width: 225.66667px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <h6 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                                <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/rallyday/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                <!-- ^^^ ADD ARTICLE 3 LINK ABOVE -->
                                  <img class="article-arrow" width="25" height="20" src="http://www.bluebeam.com/us/email/variety/html/images/arrow-right-blue.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">

                                <!-- REPLACE CONTENT BELOW FOR ARTICLE 3 --> 
                                Rally Day Is Heating Up! 
                              </a></h6>
                                  <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">We are now halfway through our Rally Day US qualifying period. Keep driving sales as we approach the final stretch. Not registered yet? <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/rallyday/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">Sign up here >> </a></p>
                                  <!-- END OF CONTENT FOR ARTICLE 3 -->
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-7 columns last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: left; width: 322.33333px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <a href="http://partners.bluebeam.com/rallyday/" target="_blank" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img src="https://downloads.bluebeam.com/images/2016/VARiety/16-07/article-3-rally-day.jpg" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">
                                  </a>
                                  <!-- ^^^ ADD IMAGE 1 URL  -->
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- END ARTICLE 3 -->
                  <!-- ARTICLE 2
                LAYOUT = IMAGE > COPY
                TO DUPLICATE SELECT FROM ROW BELOW TO END ARTICLE 2 -->
                  <table class="row row-article" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: table; padding: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                        <th class="small-12 large-7 columns first" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 8px; text-align: left; width: 322.33333px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <a href="mailto:partners@bluebeam.com" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img src="https://downloads.bluebeam.com/images/2016/VARiety/16-07/article-4-cool-down.jpg" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">
                                  </a>
                                  <!-- ^^^ ADD IMAGE 2 URL  -->
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th class="small-12 large-5 columns last" style="Margin: 0 auto; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 16px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: left; width: 225.66667px;">
                          <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                                <th style="Margin: 0; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">
                                  <h6 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                                <a href="mailto:partners@bluebeam.com" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                                <!-- ^^^ ADD ARTICLE 2 LINK ABOVE -->
                                  <img class="article-arrow" width="25" height="20" src="http://www.bluebeam.com/us/email/variety/html/images/arrow-left-blue.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: inline-block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;">

                                <!-- REPLACE CONTENT BELOW FOR ARTICLE 2 --> 
                                Cool Down With Bluebeam This Summer 
                              </a></h6>
                                  <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #C7C7C7; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">Host a Bluebeam-themed Happy Hour, complete with a Revu presentation. We’ll send the koozies, you’ll bring the customers! Contact your <a href="mailto:partners@bluebeam.com" style="Margin: 0; color: #0083db; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">Partner Relations Specialist</a>                                        to learn more.</p>
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!-- END ARTICLE 2 -->
```

Let me know if you see anything that might be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since recent versions of Windows Outlook use Microsoft Word to render emails, it often needs to be brute-forced to enforced styles that web browsers just figure out.

Two suggestions based on your code and issue reported above:
- Put inline styles at the lowest possible level (don't rely on the cascade)
- Use depracated HTML attributes like `valign` and `align`

**Specifically for your email:**

---

Place vertical alignment CSS in a `<td>` or `<th>` instead of a `<tr>`:

```
<tr style="vertical-align: top;">
    <th style=""...>
```

changes to

```
<tr style="">
    <th style="vertical-align: top;"...>
```

---

On that note... brute-force Outlook into vertical alignment by using the old and deprecated `valign=""` attribute:

```
<th valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;"...>
```

---

And make sure your padding for each row of the email matches. A simplified version could go from this:

```
  <th class="small-12 large-7 columns first" style="padding: 0; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 45px;
```

to this:

```
  <th class="small-12 large-7 columns first" style="padding: 45px 8px 40px 16px;">
```

Comment: Forcing valign seems to have removed the odd spacing inconsistencies. Thank you!